# PHP exec runs differently in CLI and NGINX

Tags: php, nginx, exec

```
 //test.php
<?php
    exec("git --version",$res1);
    var_dump($res1);
    exec("whoami",$res2);
    var_dump($res2);
?>
```

result in cli mode : php -f test.php

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "git version 2.2.1"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "nginx"
}
```

result in nginx(chrome):

```
array(0) { } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "nginx" }
```

cli and nginx all run as nginx user

Comment: Probably in nginx the `$PATH` environment variable is different and does not contain the directory where your `git` command is stored. Have you tried to use the full path to git? You can find out the full path to git with `which git` in the same terminal as you do `php -f test.php`.

Comment: Furthermore the CLI and FPM version of PHP can be distinct, and divert in their .ini settings, not just the environment vars.

Comment: cli and nginx use the same php version:5.6.35,and they use the same php.ini file.When i run 'git --version' command in terminal as nginx user,terminal response:git version 2.2.1